# re enable jquery selection

Tags: jquery, selection

I want to re-enable the selection
this was the disable:

```
function AttIvAselecT(){
$('*').attr('unselectable','on')
 .css({'-moz-user-select':'-moz-none',
       '-moz-user-select':'none',
       '-o-user-select':'none',
       '-khtml-user-select':'none',
       '-webkit-user-select':'none',
       '-ms-user-select':'none',
       'user-select':'none'
 }).bind('selectstart', function(){ return false; });
```

};

Comment: Just write opposite for your code..

Comment: sorry, I'm new in the html/jquery world...

Comment: i would suggest using classes for the active/inactive state. And then $(selector).addClass(xxxx) or $(selector).removeClass(xxxx)

Comment: You couldn't find worst selector than: `$('*')`...

Comment: @A.Wolff is it impossible? can you resolve using the '*' I need it

Comment: I've tried using removeAttr and unbind, but doesnt work....

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/98hUD/

Comment: Your DIV has an ID, so why not use it as selector instead of matching absolutely all elements inside DOM??? And BTW, ya, you should toggle a class instead as suggested by @andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [detailed in the specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) for this non-standard feature, you can use `none | text | all | element`

So in your case:

```
function UNDO_AttIvAselecT(){
    $('*').attr('unselectable','off')
    .css({'-moz-user-select':'-moz-all',
       '-moz-user-select':'all',
       '-o-user-select':'all',
       '-khtml-user-select':'all',
       '-webkit-user-select':'all',
       '-ms-user-select':'all',
       'user-select':'all'
    }).unbind('selectstart');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [UNSELECTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801966%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [**user-select**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/user-select)

```
$('*').attr('unselectable','off')
 .css({'-moz-user-select':'text',
       '-moz-user-select':'text',
       '-o-user-select':'text',
       '-khtml-user-select':'text',
       '-webkit-user-select':'text',
       '-ms-user-select':'text',
       'user-select':'text'
 }).unbind('selectstart'); // don't miss to unbind it
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/98hUD/1/)

**FYI:**

> what @A.Wolff says, * represents the entire html elements. 
>   so it is not wise to unselect all html elements, instead use if or class
>   selector